# OpenGL model Overlay of Camera Preview

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, overlay, preview

I am trying to display a .md2 model over top of the camera preview on my android phone. I don't need to use the accelerometers or anything. If anyone could even just point me in the right direction as to have to set up an opengl overlay that would be fantastic. If you are able to provide code that shows how to enable this that would be even better! It would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: can you import min3d,if yes,can you give more detail thank

Comment: i have solved,download the src also,and add to the android path,are ok

Comment: Hello Penwang, I found this: I added the min3d.jar to my project and it worked out. I still haven't gotten a model to display overtop of the camera preview as of yet, but I am working on that :) [link]http://cs.millersville.edu/~webster/cs406MDD/stuff/CodeSamples/ [/link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to provide code until later this week, but you might want to check out a library called [min3d](http://code.google.com/p/min3d/), because I believe they already have a parser written for .md2 files. Then I believe that if you use a GLSurfaceView, the background can be set to be transparent, and you can put a view of the camera behind it. Are you trying to get some kind of augmented reality effect? There are android specific libraries for that too, but they're pretty laggy (at least on my Motorola Droid).

Comment: Thanks! I did see that min3d library, but I did not know if that could be added to a project that could then be uploaded to the market.. Yes I just want to display the camera in preview and show a model or 2 in front of it. Nothing super fancy like layar with compass or accelerometer coding :) I am still a beginner when it comes to this Android stuff so I appreciate the help. I will be checking over min3d for sure! If you could lend a hand with the code later on,  I would definitely appreciate that also. Once again thanks for the response! :)

Comment: This may sound fairly n00bish, but I see the examples for min3d and I see the .src files I need but I do not understand how to import them in to my project :S Any ideas as to how I add this library?

Comment: *EDIT* I was able to add the project. I just wasn't thinking straight that the time :)